# Java error when trying to run UBCG jar (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: java

I wanna install UBCG.JAR in ubuntu 18.04 but I cannot run the java File UBCG.JAR.
when I type the code `java -jar UBCG.JAR` an error message appears.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 3 more

```
$ java -version
Openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
```

Comment: Thank you very much the problem solved, it was about JDK version

Comment: Could you please either accept an answer, or write up (and accept) your own solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong java version it should be 8

try "java -version"

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem but UBCG.JAR does not work with java 11 . It is necessary to install openjdk-8-jre and switch the default java.

**Install openjdk-8-jre**

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy openjdk-8-jre
$ sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre=1.8.0_292
```

**Switch the default java**

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
*            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081
```

**Checking the default java**

```
    $ java -version
```

openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~18.04-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)

**Run the UBGC.jar**

```
$ java -jar UBCG.jar 
      ###############################
      #         UBCG ver. 3.0       #
      ###############################
```